# How can I do the Smash Melee in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I found that in Single Player my Vanguard character can do a downward smash attack with the Melee button, similar to Nova. It activates when I Run and then Melee while running (X+O on PS3) like I'm doing a regular Strong Melee.

Shepard hits the ground for a small shockwave. It's got a bit of an AOE so it's not the same as the normal punch. It's not Nova since it doesn't drain my Biotic Barrier, and it doesn't initiate a cooldown; it's a Melee skill best I can tell.

I tried doing this move in multiplayer but it doesn't work. No matter what I try, my character does the Strong Melee normally, not the downward smash. I even tried using a Vanguard character and nothing.

Is there anything I need to do to unlock/use this attack? Why doesn't it work in Multiplayer?

I know the Asari Adept has a similar "shockwave" attack, but that's just the Asari's normal heavy melee. This is a different attack I have in *addition* to the normal heavy melee.

Comment: I thought you were talking about Super Smash Brothers :(

Comment: Have you checked the upgrade trees for Vanguard?  I'm fairly certain this is an upgrade.

Comment: @StrixVaria so does the related questions :)

Comment: You will find that Multiplayer is a lot different then Singleplayer, powers are limited and characters a lot less OP. only class i have come across with a nova melee is Asari Adepts in multiplayer atleast.

Comment: @agent86 I was thinking it might be part of Fitness, but I don't think anything explicitly mentions this attack

Comment: @Paralytic you mean Asari Adepts have this downward smash melee as well, with the same button combo?

Comment: i have no idea if its the same combo as i use xbox, but the heavy melee attack for Asari Adepts is an amazing Nova AoE

Comment: @agent86 checked the wiki's description of all Vanguard skills, none of them describe this power.

Answer (score 2):

Shepard is different from the multi player human classes.
This is an unique attack animation that only the Shepard Vanguard has, all other classes just do their normal heavy melee animation.
However, the stats are identical to the normal heavy melee of the Vanguard. In coalesced.bin there is only one set of data for the vanguard heavy melee and if you edit that, it will apply to both attacks(I gave it a very large AoE and in game that applied to both attacks).

Answer (score 1):

The only Class in Multiplayer that i know that has a heavy melee attack that does an AOE is the Asari Adept. I've played a couple Vanguards and neither had a Explosive AOE like the one i previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This AOE melee is available to all Asari in the multiplayer. The Asari Vanguard character card is an uncommon item, so if you buy enough Veteran Packs, you'll get her eventually.

Comment: It's not the same; that's a radial burst in a sphere, the attack in Single player is a downward slam very similar to Nova